# Parse MS Visio XML with Python - ElementTree

Tags: python-3.x, xml, xml-parsing, elementtree, visio

I am trying to translate a long MS Visio Document. 
I have unzipped the VCDX file and have recovered the dozens of xml files, each representing a page in the Visio Document. 
The next steps would be to extract the text, feed it into Google Translate and finally reinsert into the document

I am using ElementTree, but I cannot access the Text "content".

The structure around the text in the XML files is:

```
<Text>
   <cp IX='0'/>
   <pp IX='0'/>
   <tp IX='0'/>Here is the text 
   <cp IX='1'/>It could also be here
</Text>
```

Those cp, pp, tp is formating information. I don't know how to handle these.

My code:

```
tree = ET.parse('page1.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

for content in root.iter('{http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/visio/2012/main}Text'):
    print(content.text)
```

gives as result

```
None
None
None
None
```

Comment: "Here is the text" is the `tail` of the `<tp>` element. See https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.tail

Comment: Thank you very much, this is what I was looking for.